# Convex Subset Projection

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose that C is a closed convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$. The projection of $\mathbf x$ onto C is the closest point $\mathbf y \in C : \mathbf z = \mathbf y$ minimizes ||$\mathbf z - \mathbf x$||$_2$ over all $\mathbf z \in C$.

If $P_C$($\mathbf x$)=$\mathbf y$ is the projection function, show that $(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)^T (\mathbf z- \mathbf y) \leq 0$ for all $\mathbf z \in C$.

Hint: look at the derivative of ||$(\mathbf x - (\mathbf y + \theta (\mathbf z - \mathbf y))$||$_2^2$ with respect to $\theta$ at $\theta = 0$.

I also went to my professor's office hours and he helped me get started in the following way but I don't know where to go from here...

We have $$||\mathbf x - \theta(\mathbf z - \mathbf y)|| \geq ||\mathbf x - \mathbf y||$$ and by squaring both sides we get $$||\mathbf x - \theta(\mathbf z - \mathbf y)||^2 - ||\mathbf x - \mathbf y||^2 \geq 0$$ and then we can take the limit: $$\lim_{\theta\to0^+}\frac{||\mathbf x - \theta(\mathbf z - \mathbf y)||^2 - ||\mathbf x - \mathbf y||^2}{\theta} $$

This is an extension of a question that I already asked [Minimize Function over Convex Subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755235/minimize-function-over-convex-subset)

Answer (score 0):

The equation you want to use is this:
$$||\mathbf x -\mathbf y - \theta(\mathbf z - \mathbf y)||^2 - ||\mathbf x - \mathbf y||^2 \geq 0$$
Remember the reason this is true is that $\mathbf y + \theta(\mathbf z - \mathbf y) \in C$ for all $\theta \in [0,1]$.

To make things a little easier, first show that if
$$||\mathbf a - \theta \mathbf b||^2 - ||\mathbf a||^2 \geq 0$$
for all $\theta \in [0,1]$, then $\mathbf a^T \mathbf b \le 0$.

Comment: $||\mathbf a - \theta \mathbf b||^2 - ||\mathbf a||^2 \geq 0$

$$\sqrt{a - \theta b}^2 - \sqrt{a}^2 \geq 0$$

$$a- \theta b - a \geq 0$$

Is this how I would do this?

Comment: You need to use the correct definition of Euclidean norm. $\| \mathbf a \|^2 = \mathbf a ^T \mathbf a$